# Rcpp openmp plugin in building package

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp, r-package

When I write stand-alone cpp script, I include the openmp using  `// [[Rcpp::plugins(openmp)]]`.

However, when I try to build an R package with Rcpp, I don't know how to let the compiler know that I have a plugin. I tried to add `Plugin:openmp` in description, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You edit `src/Makevars` accordingly, that is explained in [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#OpenMP-support):

```
PKG_CFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS)
```

See Section 1.2.1.1 in the link above for details.

Comment: Thank you! You are my life saver!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but I'm afraid that I didn't fully succeed. After editing the Makevars, I no longer have the error "undefined reference to `omp_set_num_threads'", but I still have the warnings "ignoring #pragma omp parallel".  Do I need to modify the cpp script?

Comment: Adding PKG_CPPFLAGS solves the problem for me. It is written in the link, but I was careless.